# IUnknown on Xamarin/Mono, GetObjectForIUnknown throws PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, com, mono

I have unmanaged C++ classes, that implement IUnknown properly. I compile the code to a shared library and deploy the library to be used on Android phone. I implemented a simple Xamarin.Forms (C#) application, which uses this library via the standard P/Invoke. Using a factory method, I create a set of these classes, each of its own specific type (and implementing its own interface as well, thus returning `S_OK` to `QueryInterface` call with supported `iid`).

The object gets created using P/Invoked native factory method, so I obtain a valid `IntPtr`-typed pointer.

However, when I try to call

```
IntPtr myObj = NativeBridge.CreateMyObject();
var obj = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(myObj);
```

the code throws `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

The site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown?view=netstandard-2.0 states, that this method is supported on .NET Standard 2.0, which I use.

My Xamarin.Forms project is compiled as Xamarin.Android + Shared .NET Standard 2.0 Library, in MS Visual Studio 2017.

Are there some implications I missed? Is GetObjectForIUnknown truly not supported on Xamarin in this configuration? Are there any alternatives to accomplish the same/similar results? Or am I doing something completely wrong on the C# side?

EDIT1: the `Marshal.QueryInterface` call on the same `IntPtr` throws `NotImplementedException`

EDIT2: seems not supported in Mono in master: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.InteropServices/Marshal.cs - the `QueryInterface` and `GetObjectForIUnknown` method implementations are wrapped in conditionals for `MOBILE`.

So my question is: is there any way I can use COM model on Mono/Android within Xamarin.Forms, without rolling my own native library that bridges the implementations?

Comment: For how to use C++ com in Xamarin, you could check the links below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/ 
     https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/using-c-libraries-xamarin-forms-apps/

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am well aware of other means of using native libraries within managed environment. However, COM interface is a standard way of achieving interoperability without the need of a custom wrapper library. My point is, I should be able to call QueryInterface, GetObjectForIUnknown and typecast to a C# wrapper and then call methods of a managed object, which transparently calls the unmanaged IUnknown class instance.